# Работа с .rtf-файлами в PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt5, текст, rtf

Каким образом происходит запись и чтение RTF-файлов и как расположить текст из такого файла в QTextEdit?

Comment: Посмотрите https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337446/is-there-a-python-module-for-converting-rtf-to-plain-text

Comment: В QTextEdit такой файл не получится показать -- нужно хотя бы сконвертировать его в HTML